# db2 translate function equivalent in Derby for unit testing

Tags: sql, unit-testing, db2, derby

I am using Derby for my unit testing of an application that hits a DB2 database.  I only have access to the production instance so I don't want to run my tests against that database.

Is there a translation for the following in derby that would still be valid in DB2?  I am needing to validate that a string is a number.  This is a function defined in db2 so I just need to rebuild the function in my derby build script.

```
TRANSLATE(MyNumberAsString, '*', '0123456789') = 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but using different database platforms for testing and production does not make much sense to me. You will probably be better off installing DB2 for your development and testing purposes as well. DB2 Express-C edition is free.

Comment: Thanks Mustaccio, for the simple query that pulls data from db2, I didn't want to have to support an extra database.  The code is externalized in a function, so I just implemented the function in derby to mimic the DB2 function.

Comment: Your sample code is not right. The `TRANSLATE` function returns a string, but you compare it to zero. As written, it should return `MyNumberAsString` with any digits replaced by asterisk (*). Please clarify if you just want to replace `TRANSLATE` or if you want to check that `MyNumberAsString` is an integer.